# Is it possible to re-create JVM?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have quite simple code that creates a JVM instance and destroys it.

```
status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
...
status = (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
...
```

It works OK, JVM is operational, statuses are successful.

But when I try to execute it once again, it fails with a strange error "No such file or directory". In the same manner for oracle and open jdk of different versions. Could anybody explain it?

Full sample code:
https://github.com/crackcraft/create_destoy_jvm

Comment: Doesn't it tell you _which_ directory or file is missing?

Comment: No. It is a result of perror

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#destroy_java_vm

> ... The JDK/JRE still does not support VM unloading, however.

In addition, OpenJDK's bug report [JDK-4712793](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4712793) "JNI : Failure in JNI_CreateJavaVM() after calling DestroyJavaVM()" states:

> ... As of JDK/JRE 1.2 , creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported."
>
> The last line implies that that once a VM is created and destroyed, one
> cannot start another VM. A simple test case was used to reproduce the problem as specified in the pseudo-code, and the JNI_CreateJavaVM correctly returns !JNI_OK.

Comment: To add to this: you can check for an existing Java VM with `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` and reuse the one found.

Comment: JNI is BS. Then how does Java propose you add fresh options? How doe Java propose two users of the JVM will not add options that conflict in what they are trying to do?